# Enter user text in .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Im trying to make a simple command to remove all `whatever.whatever~` files, that is all hidden junk files, but I the Terminal keeps asking me for yes or no and I don't know how to hard code yes into the script.

This is what I have going on so far:

```
alias cleandir='
for i in ./*~
do
 rm "$i" 
 yes

done'
```

This results in the terminal asking me to enter yes or no for each object to be deleted, and then write an infinite amount of 'y'.

for example:

```
joel test$ cleanup
rm: remove regular file ‘./~main~.cpp~’?
```

I write yes or no, then:

```
y
y
y
y
etc...
```

How do I make my "yes" to actually be prompted in the terminal as if it was the user writing it?

First time writing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `rm -f "$i"` or pipe yes to rm `yes | rm "$i"`

Comment: @andlrc: Please write _answers_ in the _answer section_. As the name implies, that is what it is there for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use `find` for this?

```
alias cleandir="find /some/path -type f -name '*~' -delete"
```

This what I use to remove all the `.pyc` files from Python and works very well (obviously, with `-name '*.pyc'` instead).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about feeding input into your 'rm' process (more correctly, *any* process), you can either *pipe* data from a process, or *redirect* from a file e.g.

```
$ yes | rm
```

pipes the stdout of 'yes' into the stdin of 'rm'. That's useful for dynamic output from a process.

Or you can redirect from a file e.g.

```
$ rm < 'myYesFile.txt'
```

which takes the contents of `myYesFile.txt` and redirects that to the stdin of 'rm'. That's useful for a *static* set of response/input data. Note that you don't need a separate file, and you could use a *heredoc* e.g.

```
$ rm <<EOF
y
y
y
EOF
```

and declare your inputs explicitly in the shell.